# Why it shows illegal memory location when sorting vector after merge?

Tags: c++, stl

I tried to sort a new vector after merge two vector, the code like that,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void vec_output(vector <int> vec_input)
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_input.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vec_input[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    vector <int> v1{2,3,1};
    vector <int> v2{5,4,6};
    vector <int> v3;
    set_union(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), v3.begin());
    sort(v3.begin(), v3.end());
    vec_output(v3);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it shows error:`Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault`, I know it may cause by accessing unknown memory,but how?

Comment: check: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union , you need to provide std::back_inserter(v3) in set_union()

Comment: Apart from that issue, `std::set_union` operates on _sorted_ ranges.  Your vector `v1` is not sorted.  The behavior is undefined.  It is also pointless to call `std::sort` on the resulting union, since it will already be sorted.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union)? Hint: `std::back_inserter(v3)`. Also, unsurprisingly, `.begin()` on an empty vector yields something that’s only valid for comparisons against `.end()`, but not for (attempts at) dereferencing. Last but not least, `using namespace std;` is an antipattern, please don’t do that.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek I'm going to double down on the recommendation to avoid `using namespace std`.  Instead, just pull in the pieces you require, e.g. `using std::vector`.

Comment: `std::set_union()`, like a number of other algorithms, assumes that the last argument is a dereferencable iterator.  `v3` has no elements, so `v3.begin()` will be equal to `v3.end()` and dereferencing it (to write a value via it) gives undefined behaviour.       Use `std::back_inserter(v3)` instead - that produces an iterator that will append elements to `v3`.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for your reply again! I know it is better to use std::vector rather than using namespace std, but I was wondering if it is repeated when I once use it. is there better method can avoid it?

Comment: "is there better method can avoid it?" sure - `using ivector = std::vector<int>` and then use `ivector` in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **problem** is that `v3` is empty so writing `v.begin()` as the last argument to `set_union` isn't possible. You should use `back_inserter` as:

```
set_union(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(),  std::back_inserter(v3));
```

The `std::back_inserter` will return an **output iterator** `back_insert_iterator` that will use `v3.push_back` to append/push_back elements into `v3`.

Also, from [std::set_union documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union):

> Elements are compared using operator< and the **ranges must be sorted** with respect to the same.

(Emphasis mine)

Note also that after using `set_union` you **don't need** to use `std::sort` on `v3`.

Comment: This is not a full story. If `set_union` is called on ranges that are not sorted (`v1` and `v2`), the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: You should also add that sorting set_union output is not needed.

Comment: There's no need for an insert-iterator if ` v3` is initialized with the correct size.